# Publishing ASP.NET MVC to Azure -- works locally but not on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I've been investigating this thing for hours but couldn't understand what's the problem causing this behavior.

I have built a simple ASP.NET MVC app to upload and delete photos from a predefined container on the Azure Storage Server.
It works perfectly when I run the application on my machine, locally. 
Also, it works perfectly when I run this on my machine but the Data service is located on Azure.

But, when Publishing the application to Azure, surfing to this website runs to this uninformative error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current
>   custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the
>   application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons).
>   It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server
>   machine.
>
> Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be
>   viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within
>   a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the
>   current web application. This  tag should then have its
>   "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

> Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a
>   custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the
>   application's  configuration tag to point to a custom
>   error page URL.

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This doesn't tell me anything, also - nothing like this happens when running on my machine with Visual Studio.

If you have any idea what's going on here I'd really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: Can you try by changing the customErrors mode to "Off"? You should be able to see stack trace of the error.

Comment: Did you publish your application in release mode? Do you have any config transformation going on?